# spray content-disposition with chunked transfer file download

Tags: scala, download, akka, spray, content-disposition

I have a Spray app running on Jetty which sends a PDF to the client.  It is convenient to send the file in chunks, because it can potentially get very big in size.

The problems is despite setting the `Content-Disposition` and `Media-Type` field, the file is getting rendered in the browser rather than the getting downloaded.

The `recieve()` method  of the responsible actor:

```
  val chunkIterator: Iterator[HttpData] = httpData.iterator
  def receive = {

    case FirstChunk if chunkIterator.hasNext =>
      val starterResponse = HttpResponse(headers = List(HttpHeaders
        .`Content-Disposition`.apply("attachment", Map("filename" -> FILENAME)))
        , entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/pdf`, chunkIterator.next)
        )
      ctx.responder ! ChunkedResponseStart(starterResponse).withAck(ResponseAck)

    case FirstChunk =>
      ctx.responder ! ChunkedResponseStart(HttpResponse(entity = Empty))
      context.stop(self)

    case ResponseAck if chunkIterator.hasNext =>
      val nextChunk = MessageChunk(chunkIterator.next)
      ctx.responder ! nextChunk.withAck(ResponseAck)

    case ResponseAck =>
      ctx.responder ! ChunkedMessageEnd
      context.stop(self)

    case error => log.warning("connection closed due to  {}", error)
  }
```

The headers seen from the browser

```
Content-Disposition → attachment; filename=file.pdf
Content-Type → application/pdf
Date → Fri, 04 May 2015 09:13:57 GMT
Server → Jetty(9.2.10.v20150310)
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
```

Any clues as to how can it be forced to download the file ?

Alternate Approach with `MetaMarshallers.streamMarshaller[T]`

```
 implicit val pdfStreamMarshaller = MetaMarshallers.streamMarshaller[Array[Byte]]
  val route = {
    path("api" / "pdfservice") {
      post {
        respondWithHeader(`Content-Disposition`("attachment", Map(("filename", "some.pdf")))) {
          respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/pdf`) {
            entity(as[Params]) {
              params => {
                ctx => {
                  onComplete(
                    getPdfStream(params)
                  ){
                    case Success(value) =>  ctx.complete(value)
                    case Failure(ex) => ctx.complete(s"Oops, error encountered ${ex.getMessage}")
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

private def getStream(params: Params) :Future[Array[Byte]]
```

edit: fixed the compile issues with approach 2 [converting data to `Stream[T]` ], but it still has the same issues, file download option not showing instead it is getting rendered as text in the browser. Tested with various browsers over various operating systems.

Comment: Is there any reason not to return a `Stream[T]` use spray's [built in stream marshaller](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/269ce885d3412e555237bb328aae89457f57c660/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/marshalling/MetaMarshallers.scala#L59)?

Comment: I copied your `starterResponse` almost verbatim into the on-spray-can and on-jetty examples of the latest spray source code and there it definitely works. In the past some browser (IE...) had some issues with interpreting `Content-Disposition`, so maybe it's a browser issue?

Comment: @jrudolph could this be caused by lack of an explicit ```Marshaller``` ? I had a simple function which converts the generated PDF stream to ```HttpData``` ```private def arrayToHttpData(data: ByteArrayOutputStream) = {
    Iterable(data.toByteArray).map(HttpData.apply)
  }```

Comment: @jrudolph : I was testing using latest version of Chrome/Firefox on Linux

Comment: (one year late)thanks @jrudolph. It was indeed a browser issue.